# Validate dynamically added UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms

i have added a  usercontrol dynamically to a panel of winform
 i have added the control dynamically so i want to validate the control in the winform so i have used this method

```
   private bool mobilemanu()
    {
        return panel1.Controls.OfType<UserControl1>().Select(uc => uc.comboBox1).Any(cb => cb.Text == String.Empty);
    }
```

and in the button click event i used

```
       private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool mobil = mobilemanu();

        if (!mobil)
{
    //do this
}
    else
{
    //do that
}
}
```

also along with such i used this code for showing which control is not filled properly 
but it is only showing first control as errored
i am a newbie to programming so i am little bit confused here

```
         private void mobilemanuval()
    {
        bool val = mobilemanu();
        if (val == true)
        {
            foreach (Control ctrl in panel1.Controls)
            {
                if (ctrl is UserControl1)
                {
                    UserControl1 myCrl = ctrl as UserControl1;

                    {
                        if (myCrl.comboBox2.Text == string.Empty)
                        {
                            errorProvider1.SetError(myCrl.comboBox1, "entersomething");
                        }
                        if (myCrl.comboBox2.Text == string.Empty)
                        {
                            errorProvider1.SetError(myCrl.comboBox2, "entersomething");
                        }

                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you just mixed up controls because their names only differ in last letter of the name (digit)? Does this work:

```
                    if (myCrl.comboBox1.Text == string.Empty)
                    {
                        errorProvider1.SetError(myCrl.comboBox1, "entersomething");
                    }
                    if (myCrl.comboBox2.Text == string.Empty)
                    {
                        errorProvider1.SetError(myCrl.comboBox2, "entersomething");
                    }
```

Comment: yup, that was a silly eye mistake, iavnt seen, sorry i you have distrb

Comment: No problem, things like that happen :)